# Crop Image From Image Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I am using **UIImagePickerController** to select image from *camera* or *gallery* in my SwiftUI app. I set **allowsEditing** to **true**. After setting it to true it is showing a square to select the photo like this:

[image: image selection]

I want to select image of size (e.g **width = 150** and **height = 150**) instead of that **square**. Can I do that in SwiftUI. If yes, how can I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

public struct ImagePickerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    private let sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
    private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    public init(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
        self.sourceType = sourceType
        self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
    }

    public func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = self.sourceType
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        return picker
    }

    public func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {}

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(
            onDismiss: { self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() },
            onImagePicked: self.onImagePicked
        )
    }

    final public class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        private let onDismiss: () -> Void
        private let onImagePicked: (UIImage) -> Void

        init(onDismiss: @escaping () -> Void, onImagePicked: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) {
            self.onDismiss = onDismiss
            self.onImagePicked = onImagePicked
        }

        public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            
            if let img = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                
                self.onImagePicked(img)
                
            } else if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.onImagePicked(image)
            }
            self.onDismiss()
        }

        public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_: UIImagePickerController) {
            self.onDismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

I had tried **allows editing** which gives me the square to select the photo but I need my given **width and height** selection of the photo. This is the desired result:

[image: desired]

Comment: did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @SajjadEmad I ended up using third party library for this. Here is the [link](https://github.com/zhxf2012/CropImageView)

Comment: Thank you. That should be really helpful.